# jQuery copy src of one image to another on click

Tags: jquery, html

What can I do to make this happen. I want that if I click the `imgThumb1` image the src of this image is copied on the `mainIMG`, but the image don't change when I click it... what should I do?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.propertyResultImageThumb img[alt="imgThumb1"]').click(function(){
        var trial = $('img[alt="imgThumb1"]').attr('src');
        $("#mainIMG").attr("src", trial);
    });
});


<img alt="mainIMG" src="" id="mainIMG"/>
<img alt="imgThumb1" src="http://..../uploads/2012/09/Villa-Located-In-Almansa.jpg" />
```

Comment: where is propertyResultImageThumb in your html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img[alt="imgThumb1"]').click(function(){
        var trial = $('img[alt="imgThumb1"]').attr('src');
        $('img[alt="mainIMG"]').attr("src", trial);
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8qnNG/1/)

---

my code

```
$(function(){
    $('#first').click(function(){
        $("#second").attr("src", $(this).attr('src'));
    });
});

<img src="" id="first"/>
<img src="" id="second" />
```

Answer (score 1):

try wrapping your html in a container which will have class propertyResultImageThumb

```
<div class="propertyResultImageThumb ">
<img alt="mainIMG" src="" id="mainIMG"/>
<img alt="imgThumb1" src="http://..../uploads/2012/09/Villa-Located-In-Almansa.jpg" />
</div>
```

and after that do it like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.propertyResultImageThumb img[alt="imgThumb1"]').click(function(){
        var trial = $(this).attr('src');
        $("#mainIMG").attr("src", trial);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a parent dom element with class name "propertyResultImageThumb "
 Check the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/erwKP/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy an image without it to be downloaded from the server again(in case of captcha, it could change) then this code should be used:

```
$(function(){
    $('#first').click(function(){
        img_copy(document.getElementById('#first'),document.getElementById('#second'));
    });
});

//copy src to destination without destination to download the image
function img_copy(src,destination)
{
     var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(src, src.width, src.height);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    destination.src = dataURL;
}



<img src="" id="first"/>
<img src="" id="second" />
```